# In cordova local notifications plugin?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to know In using Cordova Local notification plugin,the time taken by it is default to system time or we need to change anything like UTC+ 5:30 or IST in time formats ? when i used it i don't get any local notification output.needed help?

Comment: If you haven't used it yet then use it and see by yourself. Once you have a problem / error / don't understand the code, only then open a question. Good luck buddy :)

Comment: @ Liron Ilayev I used it but local notifications are not working that's why i asked this question and i need the solution regarding time formats i..e, IST or GMT etc..

Comment: If it returns in IST or GMT first search for it on google, and about your issue please add code so other people and I can find the bug or error that causes the lack of output.

Comment: @ Liron Ilayev K..sure tq